# Настройка NavigationService и NavigationView в одном месте

Tags: c#, mvvm, инспекция-кода, uwp, dependency-injection

## Введение

Основная цель заключается в настройке `NavigationService` и `NavigationView` в одном месте. Для того, чтобы минимизировать последствия в случае добавления или удаления элемента навигации `NavigationItem.` Не заниматься поиском нужного кода в разных местах проекта. Я бы хотел получить отзыв о достоинствах и недостатках моей реализации поставленной задачи. Код рабочий, ставлю тег `инспекция-кода`.

У нас есть `Page` с `NavigationView` и `Frame`. Расположено в `ShellPage` и контролируется `ShellViewModel`. Когда пользователь нажимает один из элементов навигации `NavigationItem`, нужно выполнить переход (`NavigatonTo()`) к выбранной странице. Чтобы делать это необходимо выполнить два действия. Во первых, создать словарь `Dictionary` в качестве реестра допустимых страниц. Где ключ это полное имя типа `ViewModel`, а значение это тип `View`.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> _pages;
typeof(TViewModel).FullName; // Ключ
typeof(TView); // Значение
```

Второе действие состоит в создании элементов навигации `NavigationItem` и добавлении их к `NavigationView`.

```
private void AddNavItem<TViewModel>(string title, Symbol symbol)
{
    var item =  new NavigationViewItem
    {
        Content = title,
        Icon = new SymbolIcon(symbol),
        Tag = ConvertToKey<TViewModel>()
    };

    _navigationView.MenuItems.Add(item);
}
```

Я видел некоторые примеры по созданию навигации в UWP приложениях. Например, [приложения](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/tree/master/samples/navigation/MixedNavigationSample.MVVMLight) созданные с помощью `Window Template Studio`, или в большом примере [приложения](https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample) от Microsoft. Оба имею *несколько* мест для описанных двух действий. Я бы хотел иметь одно место. Первый абзац описывает почему.

## Описание

Приложение стартует с `app.xaml.cs`. Методы `OnLaunched` и `OnActivated` вызывают `ActivationService`. Цель по умолчанию, создать `ShellPage` через вызов конструктора и перейти на `MainPage` Больше информации [здесь](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/master/docs/activation.md). Не относится к посту.

Начну описание с вызова конструктора `ShellPage`. Внутри вызов метода `InitializeNavigation()`.

```
// shellFrame и navigationView это имена Frame и NavigationView элементов разметки XAML
ViewModel.InitializeNavigation(shellFrame, navigationView);
```

Метод выглядит так

```
public void InitializeNavigation(Frame frame, NavigationView navigationView)
{
    _navigationView = navigationView;
    _navigationView.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

    NavigationService.Initialize(frame);
    NavigationService.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
    NavigationService.NavigationFailed += Frame_NavigationFailed;

    new NavigationConfig(NavigationService, _navigationView);
}
```

Необходимые два шага для настройки навигации находятся здесь (то самое *одно место*).

```
new NavigationConfig(NavigationService, _navigationView);
```

С одной стороны, мне **не** нужна ссылка на этот экземпляр в будущем. С другой стороны, я бы хотел разделить настройку навигации от `ShellViewModel`. Может сделать его полностью статическим? Нынешний вариант выглядит экзотично.

Для добавления в словарь

```
private void ConfigureNavService()
{
    _navigationService.Configure<ShellViewModel, ShellPage>();
    _navigationService.Configure<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    _navigationService.Configure<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
}
```

Для добавления `NavigationItem` в `NavigationView`

```
private void ConfigureNavView()
{
    AddNavItem<MainViewModel>("Home", Symbol.Home);
    // Элемент Параметры (Settings) создается разметкой XAML
    // IsSettingsVisible="True" 
}
```

И наконец, до показа всего кода, нужно отметить два статических метода.

```
public static string ConvertToKey<TViewModel>() => typeof(TViewModel).FullName;
public static string GetPageKey(NavigationViewItem item) => item.Tag.ToString();
```

Только `ConvertToKey()` знает как создать ключ из `TViewModel`. Это сделано для того, чтобы иметь только одно место по созданию ключа и не повторять этот код там, где ключ нужен. `NavigationConfig` как раз отличное место. Поскольку именно тут ключ создается и добавляется к элементу и в словарь. Метод нужен в трех местах: `NavigationConfig.AddNavItem()`, `NavigationService.Configure()`, `NavigationService.NavigateTo()`.

Похожая история с `GetPageKey()`. Только этот метод знает где хранится ключ в `NavigationItem` (свойство `Tag`). Этот метод нужен в двух местах: `ShellViewModel.OnItemInvoked()` и `ShellViewModel.IsMenuItemForPageType()`.

Спасибо за любую помощь!

## Код

**ViewModelLocator**

```
private static ViewModelLocator _current;
public static ViewModelLocator Current => _current ?? (_current = new ViewModelLocator());

private ViewModelLocator()
{
    // Services
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IActivationService, ActivationService>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

    // ViewModels
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ShellViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingsViewModel>();
}

public ShellViewModel ShellViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ShellViewModel>();
public MainViewModel MainViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
public SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SettingsViewModel>();
    
public IActivationService ActivationService => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IActivationService>();
```

**ShellPage.xaml**

```
<NavigationView x:Name="navigationView"
                IsSettingsVisible="True"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
                IsBackEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsBackEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
                Header="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected.Content, Mode=OneWay}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
                    <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemInvokedCommand}" />
                </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Grid>
                <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
            </Grid>
</NavigationView>
```

**ShellPage.xaml.cs**

```
private ShellViewModel ViewModel => ViewModelLocator.Current.ShellViewModel;

public ShellPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ViewModel.InitializeNavigation(shellFrame, navigationView);
}
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
private bool _isBackEnabled;
private NavigationView _navigationView;
private NavigationViewItem _selected;
private ICommand _itemInvokedCommand;

public bool IsBackEnabled
{
    get => _isBackEnabled;
    set => Set(ref _isBackEnabled, value);
}
public NavigationViewItem Selected
{
    get => _selected;
    set => Set(ref _selected, value);
}
public ICommand ItemInvokedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _itemInvokedCommand ?? (_itemInvokedCommand = new RelayCommand<NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs>(OnItemInvoked));
    }
}

private INavigationService NavigationService { get; }
public ShellViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    NavigationService = navigationService;            
}

public void InitializeNavigation(Frame frame, NavigationView navigationView)
{
    _navigationView = navigationView;
    _navigationView.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

    NavigationService.Initialize(frame);
    NavigationService.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
    NavigationService.NavigationFailed += Frame_NavigationFailed;

    new NavigationConfig(NavigationService, _navigationView);
}   

private void OnItemInvoked(NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateTo<SettingsViewModel>();
        return;
    }
    
    var item = _navigationView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().First(menuItem => (string)menuItem.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
    var pageKey = NavigationConfig.GetPageKey(item);
    NavigationService.NavigateTo(pageKey);
}
private void OnBackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}

private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    IsBackEnabled = NavigationService.CanGoBack;
    Selected = e.SourcePageType == typeof(SettingsPage)
               ? _navigationView.SettingsItem as NavigationViewItem
               : _navigationView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(menuItem => IsMenuItemForPageType(menuItem, e.SourcePageType));
}
private void Frame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    throw e.Exception;
}

private bool IsMenuItemForPageType(NavigationViewItem item, Type sourcePageType)
{
    var pageKey = NavigationConfig.GetPageKey(item);
    var navigatedPageKey = NavigationService.GetKeyForPage(sourcePageType);
    return pageKey == navigatedPageKey;
}
```

**INavigationService**

```
public interface INavigationService
{
    event NavigatedEventHandler Navigated;
    event NavigationFailedEventHandler NavigationFailed;

    bool CanGoBack { get; }
    bool CanGoForward { get; }

    void Initialize(Frame frame);
    void Configure<TViewModel, TView>() where TView : Page;
    string GetKeyForPage(Type page);

    void GoBack();
    void GoForward();

    void NavigateTo<TViewModel>(object parameter = null, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride = null);
    void NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter = null, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride = null);
}
```

**NavigationService**

```
public event NavigatedEventHandler Navigated;
public event NavigationFailedEventHandler NavigationFailed;

private Frame _frame;
private object _lastParamUsed;
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> _pages = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>();

private Frame Frame
{
    get
    {
        if (_frame == null)
        {
            _frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame ?? new Frame();
            RegisterFrameEvents();
        }

        return _frame;
    }
    set
    {
        UnregisterFrameEvents();
        _frame = value;
        RegisterFrameEvents();
    }
}
private Type CurrentPage => Frame.Content?.GetType();

public bool CanGoBack => Frame.CanGoBack;
public bool CanGoForward => Frame.CanGoForward;

public void Initialize(Frame frame) => Frame = frame;
public void Configure<TViewModel, TView>() where TView : Page
{
    var key = NavigationConfig.ConvertToKey<TViewModel>();
    _ = _pages.TryAdd(key, typeof(TView))
         ? true 
         : throw new InvalidOperationException($"ViewModel already registered '{key}'");
}
public string GetKeyForPage(Type page)
{
    string key = _pages.Where(p => p.Value == page).Select(p => p.Key).FirstOrDefault();
    return key ?? throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("ExceptionNavigationServicePageUnknown", page.Name));
}

public void GoBack() => Frame.GoBack();
public void GoForward() => Frame.GoForward();

public void NavigateTo<TViewModel>(object parameter = null, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride = null)
{
    NavigateTo(NavigationConfig.ConvertToKey<TViewModel>(), parameter, infoOverride);
}
public void NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter = null, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride = null)
{
    _ = _pages.TryGetValue(pageKey, out Type targetPage)
        ? true
        : throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("ExceptionNavigationServicePageNotFound", pageKey), nameof(pageKey));

    if (CurrentPage != targetPage || (parameter != null && !parameter.Equals(_lastParamUsed)))
    {
        _lastParamUsed = Frame.Navigate(targetPage, parameter, infoOverride)
                         ? parameter
                         : _lastParamUsed;
    }
}

private void RegisterFrameEvents()
{
    if (_frame != null)
    {
        _frame.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
        _frame.NavigationFailed += Frame_NavigationFailed;
    }
}
private void UnregisterFrameEvents()
{
    if (_frame != null)
    {
        _frame.Navigated -= Frame_Navigated;
        _frame.NavigationFailed -= Frame_NavigationFailed;
    }
}

private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) => Navigated?.Invoke(sender, e);
private void Frame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e) => NavigationFailed?.Invoke(sender, e);
```

**NavigationConfig**

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
private readonly NavigationView _navigationView;

public NavigationConfig(INavigationService navigationService, NavigationView navigationView)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _navigationView = navigationView;

    ConfigureNavService();
    ConfigureNavView();
}

private void ConfigureNavService()
{
    _navigationService.Configure<ShellViewModel, ShellPage>();
    _navigationService.Configure<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    _navigationService.Configure<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
}

private void ConfigureNavView()
{
    AddNavItem<MainViewModel>("Home", Symbol.Home);
    // Элемент Параметры (Settings) создается разметкой XAML
    // IsSettingsVisible="True" 
}

private void AddNavItem<TViewModel>(string title, Symbol symbol)
{
    var item =  new NavigationViewItem
    {
        Content = title,
        Icon = new SymbolIcon(symbol),
        Tag = ConvertToKey<TViewModel>()
    };

    _navigationView.MenuItems.Add(item);
}

public static string ConvertToKey<TViewModel>() => typeof(TViewModel).FullName;
public static string GetPageKey(NavigationViewItem item) => item.Tag.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу к чему пришел самостоятельно на данный момент.

## Преимущества

Задача одного места для настройки `NavigationService` и `NavigationView` действительно создает удобство для внесения изменений. Но касающихся только регистрации `ViewModel` для `NavigationService` и элементов для `NavigationView`. Процесс превращается в одну строку.

```
private void ConfigureNavService()
{
    _navigationService.Configure<ShellViewModel, ShellPage>();
    _navigationService.Configure<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    _navigationService.Configure<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
}

private void ConfigureNavView()
{
    AddNavItem<MainViewModel>("Home", Symbol.Home);
}
```

Также наличие логики по вычислению ключа и его извлечения, опять же, в одном месте `NavigationConfig`. Удобно для изменения. Не нужно править в разных частях кода.

```
public static string ConvertToKey<TViewModel>() => typeof(TViewModel).FullName;
public static string GetPageKey(NavigationViewItem item) => item.Tag.ToString();
```

## Недостатки

Отрицательная сторона полученной реализации заключается в смешении классов. Изначально независимые, самостоятельные `NavigatonServica` и `ShellViewModel` начинают зависеть от `NavigationConfig` и использовать его не только для настройки, но и в обычной работе для создания и извлечения ключа. Имею ввиду методы `ConvertToKey()`, `GetPageKey()` требующиеся в: `NavigationConfig.AddNavItem()`, `NavigationService.Configure()`, `NavigationService.NavigateTo()`, `ShellViewModel.OnItemInvoked()`, `ShellViewModel.IsMenuItemForPageType()`.

Не сказать, что сложно отследить такие связи, однако потребуется время.

## Изменения

Сохраняю принцип одного места, но с точки зрения уровней.

Ранее процесс настройки откладывался до момента прихода в `ShellViewModel.InitializeNavigation()` (вызов `NavigationConfig`). Происходят следующие изменения. `NavigationConfig` удален. Регистрация допустимых страниц и создание элементов для `NavigationView` - разные уровни. Не находятся в одном месте.

- Создание `NavigationItem` отдано разметке `XAML`. То есть там, где
  определен `NavigationView` (`ShellPage`) там и описаны элементы
  навигации.

```
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="ShellPage_MenuItem_Home" Icon="Home" Tag="Mergerify.ViewModels.MainViewModel" />
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

- Регистрация допустимых страниц происходит во `ViewModelLocator`.

```
private ViewModelLocator()
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IActivationService, ActivationService>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

    Register<ShellViewModel, ShellPage>();
    Register<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    Register<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
}

private void Register<TViewModel, TView>() where TViewModel : class
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TViewModel>();
    NavigationService.Configure<TViewModel, TView>();
}
```

Что произошло со статическими методами?

- `GetPageKey()`. Необходим для получения ключа, находящегося в
  `NavigationItem`. Поскольку теперь элементы навигации находятся в
  `ShellPage`, метод перенес в `ShellViewModel`. И это единственное
  место, где требуется данные метод.
- `ConvertToKey()`. `NavigationService` содержит словарь `_pages` с допустимыми
  страницами, имеет метод для добавления новых страниц `Configure()`. Поэтому это
  единственное место, которое знает как выглядит ключ. Для регистрации страниц создан
  метод `Configure<TViewModel, TView>()`. С его помощью регистрация проходит без
  необходимости знать как выглядит ключ. Отсюда метод `ConvertToKey()` стал
  приватным и находится в `NavigationService`.

## Вывод

Описанные изменения позволили убрать смешение классов. Каждый использует только то, что нужно ему и не связывается с другим как это было раньше. Однако первоначальная цель единого места несколько отличается от новой реализации - единого места по уровням.

На данный момент найден один баг произведенных изменений. Он заключается в том, что ключ для `NavigationItem` вписывается в разметку элемента вручную. На данный момент перешел к сокращению ключа с `Type.FullName` к `Type.Name`. Тогда в элементах навигации достаточно писать имя от `ViewModel`.